# Uialertview between switch of one uiview to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uialertview

I have two UIView's. I have an UIButton on the first view that shows the second view.
I want to trigger an UIAlertView in a thread at the first UIView and close UIAlertView when the load of the second UIView completes. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All views must be shown in the main thread so I suggest you do the following:

- On click of the first button, create a UIAlertView object and show it (with no buttons so the user cannot dismiss it).
- After the UIAlertView is created proceed to create a new thread where
  you do initialization of the other view.
- Once initialization is complete call another method on the initial
  thread which will dismiss the UIAlertView and show the view.

If you need a code sample comment on this and I'll share some code :D

Comment: I am doing as you said  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate createalert];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(show1) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; but the uialertview closes before i close it by using my code!

Comment: You should try with UIAlerViewDelegate: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html